# Adding a third-party library to chromium

Tags: chromium

I am trying to expose ndn-rtc library(https://github.com/remap/ndnrtc) functionality through chromium and having difficulties figuring out what exactly should be done. The library is an external library.

What steps should I go through to add an external library to the chromium source code?

Comment: You will have to modify corresponding ``BUILD.gn`` file to include headers/source/library files in Chromium

Comment: Could you please be more exact about that?
As there are a separate  BUILD.gn file for every third_party and a mail BUILD.gn file in the main directory.

Comment: It depends on where you want to store your third-party libraries. Just look at the contents of existing ``BUILD.gn`` and try it

Comment: @Asesh did you tried this yourself ?